# Is playing soccer allowed halal in islam

Tags: halal-haram

I want to know is playing soccer allowed halal in islam please answer my question with only yes or no thanks

Answer (score 0):

Salaam,
There is nothing haram about playing soccer, unless your making it haram. For example, if soccer is making you curse, then it may not be the best sport to engage in. Another example is if soccer is causing you to hang out with the wrong crowd and engage in haram activities after the game, then you may be making it haram. Other than that, if you are playing for fun and recreation, then you are fine!  In the Quran

Comment: what mean then you are fine, so playing soccer is halal right ??

Comment: yes it is halal